# PHP authoring tool compatible with LMS

Tags: php, scorm

I have developed a PHP authoring tool that generates 3D content. I want that Learning Management Systems can connect to this tool to generate this 3D content in a SCORM compatible format.

If my PHP authoring tool is, for example, `index.php` I imagine there is way of integrating this page into a LMS, by adding it in the manifest.

I have seen there are JavaScript APIs for generating SCO files, but I am not sure if this is possible for a whole authoring tool, or 3D content.

Should I use an API for making this PHP tool part of the LMS or should I generate directly SCORM output with the tool, and the import to a LMS? Which is the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: Your description is somewhat controversial: Do you want to create educational content with your tool, or for your tool? Will the SCORM content need access to the php files to work properly? What will it contain?

Answer (score 2):

Your tool should produce (export) a ready-to-go scorm zip package. Then anyone will be able to import it into a LMS. That's how all scorm tools work.